# Non-vanishing 2-form on quartic surface.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $S\subset \mathbb P^3$ be a quartic surface defined by a homogeneous degree 4 polynomial $F\in k[x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3]$. $S$ is a K3 surface, so it has a unique non-vanishing $(2,0)$-form $\omega$ up to scalar.

How can this $\omega$ be computed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $S$ is smooth, $\omega$ can be calculated as a [Poincaré residue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_residue) (see [Griffiths and Harris](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Sny48qKdW40C&dq=Griffiths+Harris+poincare&source=gbs_navlinks_s), pg. 147, for details).

It boils down to the following:  in an affine patch with coordinates $z_1,z_2,z_3$, where $F$ is represented by $f(z_1,z_2,z_3)$,
$$
\omega = \int_{f=0} \frac{dz_1\wedge dz_2\wedge dz_3}{f}
$$
where the integral is a higher-dimensional contour integral -- it is taken over the boundary of some arbitrarily smooth tubular neighbourhood of $S$.

Comment: So $\omega$ is by definition $\frac{dz_2\wedge dz_3}{\partial f/\partial z_1}$ if $\partial f/\partial z_1$ is not zero.

Comment: Right!  And from this point of view, the necessity that $S$ is smooth comes from the fact that in this case, $\partial f/\partial z_i$ is non-zero for at least one $z_i$ at each point.